# eclipse - restrict method line number

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

How can I tell eclipse to inform me when the number of lines in my method exceeds a certain number?

I've tried researching but ended up with nothing.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks folks!

An eclipse plugin perhaps?

Comment: Curious to know why you need this

Comment: @Sajit, I guess he need it for the code quality. He wants to make sure his methods are short enough to be readable and understandable

Comment: Yeah, @mohammadshamsi is right.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this in Eclipse.  You may have to write your own plugin or modify the existing code.  What is a "line"? Do comments count? What about whitespace?  This is not a trivial problem and would involve access to the internal AST.

Comment: @Mai, I'm not a eclipse user, but in Netbeans and IntelliJ you can use CQ plugins like PMD and Checkstyle to check for this kind of issues.

Comment: @mohammadshamsi, Yeah I've heard of PMD but I if I'm not mistaken, there's no configuration to add this kind of rule to it.

Comment: @JimGarrison, everything counts. the line count that is enclosed within the method

Comment: Limiting comment lines seems counter-productive if your line limit is low.

Comment: Well, i don't remember saying i'm limiting my method line count to 10 if that's what you mean

Comment: Checkstyle isn't going to limit you, but the warnings will certainly show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code metrics plugins for Eclipse which analyze your code and calculate statistics.
An example:
http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

The statistics include the average and maximum line numbers of methods.

Answer (score 2):

I found it:

An eclipse plugin - http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

It will show the metrics in a different panel but will not raise a warning in your eclipse though.  You need to look at the metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Install [CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/). Configure the issue detection for [method length](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit_rules_com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.auditGroup.programComplexity#com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.audit.sourceLength) in CodePro Analytix to your number of lines. Set the issue level to "Error". Then use the [dynamic auditing mode](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit#Dynamic) of CodePro Analytix. It will always scan the currently *opened editor files* for violations. So on saving a file containing a long method, you get a violation error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to consider plugins like PMD or FindBugs to improve the code quality.

Answer (score 0):

[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) can check for style issues in your code, like a method that is too long (confer  [MethodLength](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength)). There is an [Eclipse Plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) where you can configure which checks to do, what your limits are (e.g., with how many lines to report a method as "too long"), and how to display that the check failed (e.g., as an error, as a warning,...).